# Best practices for multi table join query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Tables structure are below :

```
Table1 (ID int, value1 int,...)

ID       Value1
----    --------
1        10
2        20
5        12


Table2 (ID int, value2 int,...)

ID       Value2
----    --------
1        13
3        24
4        11


Table3 (ID int, value3 int,...)
ID       Value3
----    --------
4        150
5        100
```

My expected output is below.

```
ID       Value1        Value2        Value3
----    --------      --------      --------
1         10            13             NULL
2         20            NULL           NULL
3         NULL          24             NULL
4         NULL          11             150
5         12            NULL           100
```

It should be noted that above tables is huge and I want to have best performance.

My query suggestion is below :

```
Select ID, 
       SUM(Value1) AS Value1, 
       SUM(Value2) AS Value2,
       SUM(Value3) AS Value3 
From (
    Select ID, Value1 , NULL as value2, NULL as value 3
    From Table1

    Union ALL

    Select ID, NULL , value2, NULL
    From Table2

    Union ALL

    Select ID, NULL, NULL, value 3
    From Table3
    )Z
Group By Z.ID
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you only have one value per id, this should do the trick:

```
SELECT aux.ID, t1.Value1, t2.Value2, t3.Value3
FROM 
(SELECT ID FROM Table1
 UNION
 select ID FROM Table2
 UNION
 SELECT ID FROM Table3) aux
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 t1 ON aux.ID = t1.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 ON aux.ID = t2.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 t3 ON aux.ID = t3.ID
```

---

If you've more than one value:

```
SELECT aux.ID, SUM(t1.Value1) as 'Value1', SUM(t2.Value2) as 'Value2', SUM(t3.Value3) as 'Value3'
FROM 
(SELECT ID FROM Table1
 UNION
 select ID FROM Table2
 UNION
 SELECT ID FROM Table3) aux
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 t1 ON aux.ID = t1.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 ON aux.ID = t2.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 t3 ON aux.ID = t3.ID
GROUP BY aux.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I intially wrote the same answer as aF. did above. So, removed it, and used a different approach.

Here,

> - 1st query get all from table1
> - 2nd query gets all from table2 skipping
> - those already present in table1 3rd query gets all remaining skipping    those in above two query.

```
  SELECT T1.ID, T1.VALUE1, T2.VALUE2, T3.VALUE3 --all T1
  FROM TABLE1 T1
      LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON T1.ID=T2.ID
      LEFT JOIN TABLE3 ON T1.ID=T3.ID
UNION
  SELECT T2.ID, T1.VALUE1, T2.VALUE2, T3.VALUE3 --all T2 where T1 is NULL
  FROM TABLE1 T2
      LEFT JOIN TABLE1 ON T2.ID=T1.ID
      LEFT JOIN TABLE3 ON T2.ID=T3.ID
  WHERE T1.ID IS NULL
UNION
  SELECT T3.ID, T1.VALUE1, T2.VALUE2, T3.VALUE3 --all T3 where T1 is NULL AND T2 IS NUL
  FROM TABLE1 T3
      LEFT JOIN TABLE1 ON T3.ID=T1.ID
      LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON T3.ID=T2.ID
  WHERE T1.ID IS NULL
        AND T2.ID IS NULL
```